# Please explain this TweenJS code

Tags: createjs, tweenjs

Am a newbie in CreateJS and i have use this example code but don't understand it that much coz there is no code by code exaplaination.
The code is the one below:

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, { loop: true })
  .to({ x: 400 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
  .to({ alpha: 0, y: 175 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
  .to({ alpha: 0, y: 225 }, 100)
  .to({ alpha: 1, y: 200 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
  .to({ x: 100 }, 800, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
```

Can someone explain it for me please.Step by step.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tween for the `circle` object. It will loop through instructions:

`createjs.Tween.get(circle, { loop: true })`

Tween calls are "chained", so by appending methods, it will run them in order. Technically, each method just returns a reference to the tween so you can call a bunch in order. The line breaks in the code make it more readable, but it is basically:

```
tween.to(values).to(values).to(values);
```

The first tween sets the `x` position of the circle to 400px in a 1000 millisecond animation. It has an ease on it that has a custom value. Check out the [TweenJS Ease class](http://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Ease.html) for more.

```
.to({ x: 400 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4))
```

After the first animation, it will then set the `alpha` and `y` values over 500ms, with a slightly different ease.

```
.to({ alpha: 0, y: 175 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
```

The rest should make sense.

```
.to({ alpha: 0, y: 225 }, 100)
.to({ alpha: 1, y: 200 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2))
.to({ x: 100 }, 800, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
```

You can also chain other methods on Tween, such as `call()` to call a function, or `set` to change other properties on the tween target that are not being tweened.

Just for reference, this is the same as something more traditional like this:

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(circle, { loop: true });
tween.to({ x: 400 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(4));
tween.to({ alpha: 0, y: 175 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
tween.to({ alpha: 0, y: 225 }, 100);
tween.to({ alpha: 1, y: 200 }, 500, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
tween.to({ x: 100 }, 800, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks alot @Lanny for the explanation.I think i now get the concept pretty well.